# Help with Pixastic Resize using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to use Pixastic with jQuery, looking for advice or any examples of it being used with jQuery?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/#jquery for documentation. If you have a specific question, you'll have to be more concrete.